# Getting data from python with JS and plotting it, with Django backend and Google maps api

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, google-maps

I've got a project with a django backend that I'm using for logins, and using the mysql DB through my local host. I currently have my `gettweets.py` script returning an array of coordinates and have a JS script that is supposed to get these results and plot it to google maps api. My JS script fails at `$.get`. However, if i go to `127.0.0.1/gettweets?tag=%23Pizza`, I get something like this:

```
["-87.634643, 24.396308", "-80.321683, 25.70904", "-79.639319, 43.403221", "-95.774704, 35.995476", "-84.820309, 38.403186", "-120.482386, 34.875868", "-121.385009, 38.716061", "-111.530974, 40.619883"]
```

I've been trying to get JS to make the call on the button click because I don't think I can get the results to it through Django. Why is it getting stuck?

Here is the JS inside of index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.13,-100.32),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

      }

      // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
      // set of coordinates.
      $('#searchButton').click(function(){
                    $.get('../../gettweets?tag=%23Trump', function(data, status) {
                      alert(status);
                        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
                        alert('data');
                        data.forEach(function(point) {
                            var coordString = point['coord'];
                            var x = coordString.substring(0,coordString.indexOf(','));
                            var y = coordString.substring(coordString.indexOf(',')+1,coordString.length);
                            console.log(x);
                            console.log(y);
                            var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
                            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latLng,
                                map: map
                            });
                        });
                        window.myLine.update();
                    });
                    //xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    //var tag = document.getElementById('tagSearch').value;
                    //if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

                    //}


                    //xmlhttp.open("GET","./getTweets.php?tag='" + tag + "'");
                    //xmlhttp.send();

    });
      </script>
```

Button/form:

```
<form>
       <input id="tagSearch" type="text" name="tag" maxlength="100" required placeholder="{{ tag }}" />
       <button class="btn waves-effect red" type="submit" id="searchButton" name="search">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
       </form>
```

`gettweets.py` - NOTE I've got this in my views, as well as a separate file. I'm not sure which one I need with the JS

```
def tweets(request):
    tag = request.GET['tag']
    print(tag)

    x = models.Tweet.objects.filter(tag=tag)
    print(x)
    coords = []
    for i in x:
        coords.append(i.coord)

    print(coords)
    return JsonResponse(coords, safe=False)
```

Finally, urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^gettweets$', views.tweets, name='gettweets'),

]
```

Comment: What is the response from the server? Is it a 500 error? A 404?

Comment: There is no error from the server. The .get call immediately stops the rest of that script which I seen from debugging, thats all I've figured out about that so far.

Comment: To clarify, it reaches `$.get('../../gettweets?tag...)`, you see a 200 response in your development server console, but you never reach `alert(status)`?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: If you add `alert('test');` above the `$.get` line, does it show the alert?

Comment: Yes it does @J.McBride

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `$.get()` incorrectly.  Its signature is `$.get(url[, data][, success][, dataType])`, from the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

I would prefer using a settings object like so:

```
$.get({
  url: '../../gettweets?tag=%23Hillary',
  success: function (data, status) {
    ...
  }
});
```